.net core web api connection to oracle server with kerberos authentication
I need to make a request to an Oracle database using Kerberos authentication. The request is made from a .NET Core Web API that is hosted in IIS. In IIS, I'm using an application pool identity set up for a specific account that has the necessary permissions to access the database.
The problem is, I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this. Currently, I get the following error from my .NET Core Web API:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-01017/
I have the necessary configuration files for the connection:

krb5.conf
sqlnet.ora

Connection String I'm using:

string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxx)));User Id=/;";

Questions:

Is it even possible to connect to an Oracle database using Kerberos authentication from a .NET Core Web API hosted in IIS?
Am I missing something in the configuration, or is there another approach I should be using?
Is there a way to verify if the IIS application pool identity is being used for Kerberos authentication when making the request to the Oracle database?

